# Still getting uncaught TypeError even after including underscore

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I've looked and seen the messages about putting underscore before backbone and marionette.  I've done that.  When I run my sample I still get:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined
>       at MessageDetailsView.js:1

I'm not trying to instantiate the view, so it doesn't seem that I would need a model yet.

I'm trying to convert my html/jquery to marionette and this is my start.  Once I get the `ItemView` to load, then I will see if I can put it in a `CollectionView` or just add directly to a div.

Any thoughts?

**main.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">

<head>
    <title>Gmail API Quickstart</title>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
</head>

<body>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="underscore_1_8_3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="backbone.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="backbone.radio.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="backbone.marionette_3_2_0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="MessageDetailsView.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Start");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**MessageDetailsView.js**

```
var MessageDetailsView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({

});
```

Comment: The browser cannot find .extend({ }), hence, undefined. That's what the error is pointing at.

Comment: Which version of Marionette are you using?

Comment: I'm in better shape now.  I pulled up the 3.0 documentation and was able to port my 2.x example to the newer version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 3.2.0 of Marionette doesn't have an `Marionette.ItemView` class, it has been replaced by `Marionette.View`, see [docs](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v3.0.0/marionette.view.html).

Use v2.4.7 if you want the [ItemView](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.7/marionette.itemview.html) class.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm very new to marionette and mistakenly assumed the versions would be the same.  I have gotten my items added to the DOM now.